# How can we add different sound to spinner (music play)

Tags: java, android, spinner

I would like to create am timer application(with alarm) for android mobile .
I can able to make timer with one sound. By storing the .mp3 in Raw folder

A drop down which contain sound list would be interesting. Bt in android their is no drop down option. I found Spinner is helpful in this.

Problem:= How can we add different sound to spinner...

Answer (score 2):

Check out [RingtonePreference](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/preference/RingtonePreference.html) it includes all the code you need, and you don't have to code the play on option change etc...
Thus the saving and reading is done for you too in your application only preference file.